# Expression in control source and default value

Tags: ms-access

I am pulling my hair here.
I want to link 2 subform fields to a field in the main form.
I used `Parent.MyFieldName.Column(3)` for the control source of the first subform field and it is displayed fine. The Row source of my second subform field is using the first subform field as a criteria for its query.
The problem is that this combobox remains empty when I use the above code but is populated if I give the first field a constant value.
Feels like the combobox is getting filled before the retrieval of data from the first subform field.
I tried moving the above code form control source to default value but then both fields remain empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you wish to refer to the first subform field rather than the parent field to which it refers? Posting a few rowsources might be a good idea.

Comment: Because when I enter Parent.MyFieldName.Column(3) in the query builder I get an error saying "Undefined function 'Parent.MyFieldName.Column' .

Comment: What is the query you are building? Please post the SQL including where you want the parent bit to go, it should be possible to rewrite the query so it works without this complication. Please include the rowsource for the parent combo, too.

Comment: Are you sure you can help with my question?

Comment: No, but over the years I have managed to help quite a few people, so it is by no means impossible.

Comment: Why are you joining on recipe to get the product rather than joining ProductBatches? That would allow you to refer to the bound column of your combo, which should always be your aim, and still get the product. Also, do you have a product ID or is product your ID?

Comment: Why did you delete the useful information you added?

Comment: While my way of naming fields and query building skills might be very poor. The problem in hand wasn't related to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the main reason why things weren't working - Subform controls load before the rest of the main form. This means that at the time my subform dropdown menu seeks the data in the other form fields they still haven't appeared and thus I am left with an empty dropdown menu.

I solved this by removing the sourceobject of the subform control and adding

```
Me!Subform1.SourceObject = "SubformOtpuskaneIzhMat"
```

In some events in the main form.

Comment: +1, interesting. How did you find out that load order ? Is it impacted by the main form's tab order ?

Comment: It is actually written here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/order-of-events-for-database-objects-HA010238988.aspx?CTT=1#BM3 (under "Working with subforms") . It is weird how much time it took me to find it though.