# Parameters in rowsource query

Tags: ms-access

I have a combobox query that uses parameters from a parent item. When I first load the form the combobox is empty, if I go to design view and return to form view the combobox is populated with the correct items.

While searching for the cause of this I decided to create an extra text field that retrieves the same data from the same parent item. On the first launch that textbox is populated while the combobox remains empty.

My last step was to change the combobox query parameter to refer to the newly created textbox. After that the previously working textbox started out empty as well and became populated after going to design view and back.

My hypothesis - the query tries to retrieve the parameters before the text fields are filled. Keep in mind I have reversed loading order of main-form and sub-form [as explained here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097227/expression-in-control-source-and-default-value)
I don't know what to google for any more

Comment: What happens when you requery the subform and / or combo in the current event of the main form?

Comment: When I add `Me.Subform1.Form.Requery` to the main form current event the text boxes in the subform start out filled in, instead of being empty when the combobox refers to them. Still the combobox remains empty if I don't go to design view and back to form view. If I want to requery the combobox how do I refer to it with relative path?

Comment: The combobox is `Me.Subform1.Form.MyCombo` You should post the Row Source of the combo.

Comment: This solved it. I got rid of the extra textboxes. My Rowsource is a query that has a parameter in one of its fields called `[Parent]![Text4]`. Your code works. Put it as an answer for me to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can requery the combo in the current event of the main form like so:

```
Me.Subform1.Form.MyCombo.Requery
```

Comment: I am really confused right now. Although it works in the current situation if I alter the query of the subform to add more fields it stops requerying. That is I have to go in design view and back for the combobox to get populated. What could be the relation between the two?

Comment: It sounds in many ways as if you are using MS Access in a non-standard way. Generally the subform is limited by the parent form based on link child and link master fields.

Comment: Do not use [Parent]![Text4], use Forms!MyForm!Text4

Comment: Changing to Forms![MainFormName]!Text4 did do the trick. I don't see the logic behind that behaviour though.

Comment: Parent does not exist at the time you refer to it, I reckon.

Comment: Sorry about the misunderstanding I was wrong when I said it worked. Forms!MyForm!Text4 in the combobox criteria still doesn't let me add new fields to the query of the subform.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13754/discussion-between-remou-and-hristo-dobrev)

Comment: Here is something extra weird - I decided to check on which event can Forms![MainFormName]!Text4 be called in the subform. I started with a MsgBox in form_load and without any requeries the combobox gets populated. Only from using a MsgBox ... this software is insane.